# Form control not revalidating

Tags: java, codenameone

I use 2 Buttons to get a list of popular places and hotels from a webservice and display in a multilist.

**Button 1** for popular places

**Button 2** for hotels

When I click on Button 1 it displayed all the requested list but when I go back to click Button 2 it return the list of hotels **join** with the list of popular places that was displayed earlier.

I want when I click on Button 1 it should return the list of popular places and when I go back to click Button 2 it should return **ONLY** the list of hotels. 
I tried to revalidate the form but no luck.
Here is my code:

```
protected void beforeFormA(Form f) {
        Button bn = new Button("Exit");
        Container c = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        switch (i) {
            case 1://for Button 1
                Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Button");
                FontImage p = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PORTRAIT, s);
                EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(p.scaled(p.getWidth() * 3, p.getHeight() * 4), false);
                f.setTitle("Tourist Attractions");
                getattractive();
                ArrayList arr = (ArrayList) response.get("results");
                for (Object m : arr) {
                    Map ma = (Map) m;
                    address = (String) ma.get("formatted_address");
                    name = (String) ma.get("name");
                    icon = (String) ma.get("icon");
                    data.add(createListEntry(name, address, icon));
                }
                DefaultListModel<Map<String, Object>> model = new DefaultListModel<>(data);
                MultiList ml = new MultiList(model);
                ml.getUnselectedButton().setIconName("icon_URLImage");
                ml.getSelectedButton().setIconName("icon_URLImage");
                ml.getUnselectedButton().setIcon(placeholder);
                ml.getSelectedButton().setIcon(placeholder);
                findContainer(f).add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ml);
                c.addComponent(bn);
                bn.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
                    System.exit(0);
                });
                findContainer(f).add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, c);
                f.getComponentForm().revalidate();
                break;

            case 2://for Button 2
                Style s1 = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Button");
                FontImage p1 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PORTRAIT, s1);
                EncodedImage placeholder1 = EncodedImage.createFromImage(p1.scaled(p1.getWidth() * 3, p1.getHeight() * 4), false);

                f.setTitle("Hotels");
                gethotels();
                ArrayList arr1 = (ArrayList) response.get("results");
                for (Object m : arr1) {
                    Map ma = (Map) m;
                    address = (String) ma.get("formatted_address");
                    name = (String) ma.get("name");
                    icon = (String) ma.get("icon");
                    data.add(createListEntry(name, address, icon));
                }
                DefaultListModel<Map<String, Object>> model1 = new DefaultListModel<>(data);
                MultiList ml1 = new MultiList(model1);
                ml1.getUnselectedButton().setIconName("icon_URLImage");
                ml1.getSelectedButton().setIconName("icon_URLImage");
                ml1.getUnselectedButton().setIcon(placeholder1);
                ml1.getSelectedButton().setIcon(placeholder1);
                findContainer1(f).add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ml1);
                c.addComponent(bn);
                bn.addActionListener((ActionEvent evt) -> {
                    System.exit(0);
                });
                findContainer1(f).add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, c);
                f.getComponentForm().revalidate();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you never clean your `data` list ... So previous items (added with   `data.add(createListEntry(name, address, icon));` remain.

You should clear at the begining of each case with :

```
data.clear();
```